# Solspace Tag - display entries from particular tag

Tags: solspace, tags, solspace-tag

I have a snippet which displays all entries within a channel and I want to have displayed entries only from a particular tag, but I'm not able to display tagged entries. Then I have decided to display all tagged entries without limitation (code below) but this is not working either.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="8" status="open" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}
{exp:tag:related_entries}
    {if switchee_no_results}
            <div class="no-entries"><p>No entries yet.</p></div>
        {/if}

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 category-item">
            <a href="{site_url}{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{url_title}">
    {product_image limit="1"}
            <img src="{product_image:image}" alt="{product_image:title}" class="img-responsive">
    {/product_image}    
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            </a>
        </div>

{switch='|||</div><div class="row row-category">'}

    {paginate}
    {exp:stash:set}

      {stash:pagination_links}{pagination_links}{/stash:pagination_links}

    {/exp:stash:set}
    {/paginate}

{/exp:tag:related_entries}     
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Even switching code to

```
{exp:tag:related_entries channel="products" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="8" paginate="bottom"}
<h3>{title}</h3>
{tag_paginate}
    <p>Page {tag_current_page} of {tag_total_pages}. {tag_pagination_links}</p>
{/tag_paginate}
{/exp:tag:related_entries}
```

doesn't do anything.

Another simple test - template below

```
   1. 
        {exp:tag:entries tag="test"}
    2.
        {if switchee_no_results}
            <div class="no-entries"><p>No entries yet.</p></div>
            {/if}

        <h3>{title}</h3>
    3. 
    {/exp:tag:entries}
```

is displaying only 1. for me, so it looks like `tag` tag is not working withing templates.

Any clue why is not working? I'm running EE 2.7.3 and Tag 4.2.5

Thanks

Comment: What version of Tag and EE are you using? Also, try putting your code on a regular template (not a snippet), at least to eliminate snippets as a possible point of issues. Also, looks like `{exp:tag:entries}` would be the tag to use to display entries associated with a tag: http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/entries/

Comment: OP updated. As I have mentioned previously - last test from OP is running as a regular template, not a snippet, and it looks like EE tag `tag` is not recognized at all.

Comment: If you're using `{exp:tag:entries}`, you must provide a tag either in the URL (with the correct URL "marker" segment, default being `/tag/`), or by using the `tag=""` parameter. If using `{exp:tag:related_entries}` (still not sure why you're using that tag), you need to provide an entry_id through the URL or through the `entry_id=""` parameter.

Comment: OP updated. Added `tag="test"` and still not getting anything, even `2` or `No entries yet` is not displayed. For me it just confirmation that EE tag `tag` is not recognized at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `{exp:tag:entries}` to display entries associated with a tag, but also make sure the status of those entries are set to "open", and if they aren't use the `status="some_other_status"` parameter.

Comment: Feel free to add to the solution if there are additional details to add.